# python- infinite loop in a process causes kivy instances to spawn forverer

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy, fork, spawn

I have a kivy app that uses multiprocessing to produce a processes with an infinite loop.

The code works fine on ubuntu -since linux uses forking as a default-. The problem is that in windows OS, spawning is the default so with each iteration, the process go through the code from the beginning, creating an infinite kivy GUI instances.

How can I solve this problem? This is how I start my process:

```
def f(x):
    while True:
        print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
```

## note: I don't use p.join() since the function never ends.

Comment: question1: Is your indentation correct? Question 2: What you have posted as a code will not spawn infinite instances.....Can you put more of your code so its replicable?

Comment: Could your problem and fix be the same as [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5807)?

Comment: @DarrylG thank you very much; the solution was adding  multiprocessing.freeze_support() as you suggested to the main module, add an answer so I accept it.

Comment: @JasonChia I apologize, I over simplified it. I edited the main question.

Comment: @MohammedBaashar--glad it worked.  I took your suggestion and added as an answer to make it easier for others to find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is addressed by [this kivy issue log](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5807)

**Summary**

Issue on windows (not Linux), when multiprocessing.Manager is used, kivy will repeatedly creates a new window

**Solution**

[Add Freeze Support] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) before starting multiple processing

**Example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    Process(target=f).start()
```

**Addtional Background**

[Python multiprocessing is different under Linux and Windows](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/) referred by  Mohammed Baashar (see comments)

Comment: I should note and stress again to the usage of "forking" on linux and "spawning" on windows: https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If just adding freeze_support fails you need to import multiprocessing and freeze support BEFORE importing kivy UNDER the if name == main guard.

more details here:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4744